# UIWebView with local HTML file not showing image

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

I've created webpage and import it to Xcode

The web page contains texts and images

When I load the webpage inside UIWebView the page appear but without Images

The webpage is created by iAd Producer

I've no background in HTML or CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the URL? It might be a relative one (e.g. '/img/foo.jpg').

You can add a base URL to your webview in that case:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```